# How to download locally multiple whl-files from pypi.org using script or a request?

Tags: pip, pypi, python-packaging

I need to upload pypi packages from pypi.org to our company's Artifactory registry.

Now I would visit, for example, https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/#files and I would download manually all desired versions. And we need only the ones, that matches `.+cp3(8|9|10|11|12)-(macos|win_amd64|manylinux2014_x86_64).*\.whl` regexp.

Is there any option to download multiple whls with one request or a script? (python/bash/curl/pip3)

I tried `subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--no-deps', '-d', cache_dir, package, '--index-url', 'https://pypi.python.org/simple'])`, but cons are:

- I have to run this line with each platform/version of python, that I need
- That goes with running the same code in a multiple docker containers
- It doesn't work with windows